# Is there a plan for Django to handle NoSQL databases natively?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, nosql

I really like Django. I've fiddled around a bit with Rails, but I personally prefer Django's logic. I also prefer Python over Ruby. Again, personal preferences. Despite all that, I am now switching back to Rails because of Django's lack of native support for databases like mongodb. I saw there was no plan for Django 1.5 to support NoSQL databases.

I've tried to install django-nonrel as it looked promising, but with no success. Even if I succeeded, I can't trust this fork of django considering the lack of active development. There isn't even a post to tell you what version of the dependencies to install, some of which are updating quite fast. So you run into errors that are not well-documented, and it's just an horror.

Django could be a long term investement for me, so I was wondering if there there was a plan to change Django's ORM to support NoSQL databases?

Comment: This might be a question better suited to one of Djangos mailing lists, this isn't typically classed as a "programming" question.

Comment: Have you read the official Django wiki for [NoSQL support](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NoSqlSupport) ? It talks about a [Django to MongoDB connector](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has been a lot of discussion about this on the various django project channels.

There are a number of side project and forks which allow no-sql functionality on django. There is also a wiki post from the django people which discusses some alternatives https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NoSqlSupport so you can use no sql.

So the bad news is: as of yet there is no definitive answer as to whether anything no-sql will be included in the django core. But the good news is there are a number of no-sql options which are supported and being developed.

Comment: Ok I just wanted confirmation thanks. I've suscribed to the django mailing list.

Comment: For awareness, MongoEngine is another Django ORM that specifically is adding support for MongoDB. 10gen is involved in its development.

http://mongoengine.org/

Comment: i would recommend [DJONGO](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/) as you won't loss the great authentication and admin panel modules from django. while using [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/) you won't be able to use many of the django default modules which are strictly based on sql databases

Comment: What about for non-Mondo NoSQL? i.e. thinking about possibly a PostgreSQL document DB. Something possibly compatible with a dotnet backend integration, MartenDB, etc.